# How can I make tox run in a clean environment?

Tags: git, tox

Once in a while I run tox, everything works, but when somebody else downloads the repository it doesn't because I forgot to commit something.

I like `tox` because it prevents me from forgetting to add requirements to `setup.py`. Can I make it also run in an environment which only has stuff that is commited or staging? (without removing, so `git clean` is not an option except if I can get it back after the tests)

Answer (score 1):

Clone development repository into a new clean one and run `tox` there. You don't need to clone the entire repo, a shallow clone with depth 1 is often enough; commercial cloud CI services by default use 50.

```
git clone -depth 1 development clean
cd clean
tox
```